# Python Webscraping: Iterating through a for loop to read a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read through a table of asteroid data found on wikipedia here:(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exceptional_asteroids) I am successfully able to print the loops through the  portions of html code associated with each row of the table. But when I attempt to store each individual cell in a variable I'm given the error that "col[0]=name" is out of range. When I remove the data storage lines it iterates 39 times through each row of the table and prints out each column.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import bs4
import html5lib
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exceptional_asteroids"
data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text,"html5lib")
Meteor_Data=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name","Diameter (km)","Dimensions (km)","Mean Distance from Sun","Inclination","Date Discovered","Discoverer","Class"])
i=0
for row in soup.find('table').find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    col=row.find_all("td")
    print("THIS IS ITERATION ",i,":",col)
    i=i+1    
    name=col[0]
    diameter=col[2]
    dimensions=col[3]
    mean=col[4]
    inclin=col[5]
    date=col[6]
    disco=col[7]
    class_=col[8]
    Meteor_Data=Meteor_Data.append({"Name":name,"Diameter (km)":diameter,"Dimensions (km)":dimensions,"Mean Distance from Sun":mean,"Inclination":inclin,"Date Discovered":date,"Discoverer":disco,"Class":class_})
print(Meteor_Data)
```

Comment: Probably there is an empty row in the table. Check the number of items in the row and skip it if there aren't enough items in it.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is in your selection, `table` has different structur in `tr` because there are some `td` with `colspan` and also take a closer look to the `soup` you get, there are also `tr` with `th` so your picking by index will break.

So select more specific:

```
for row in soup.select('table:-soup-contains("Date discovered") tr:not(:has(th,td[colspan]))'):
    col=row.select('td')
```

Also do not `append()` to `dataframe`, there will be issues with newer versions of `pandas` instead `concat` oder simple store your `dicts` in a `list` and use `pd.DataFrame([YOUR LIST OF DICTS HERE])`

Or even better use `pandas` you could work with `pandas.read_html()`:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exceptional_asteroids')[0]
df[~df.Name.str.contains('resonance\)')].dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```